# Is there a Way to detect that an Email could not be delivered using Gmail API?

Tags: java, google-api, gmail-api

When sending an email using the Gmail API you can use any mailaddress to deliver the message to.
What if that email is a wrong emailaddress and it is impossible to deliver the message?
The label will still be set to SENT right?

Is it possible to detect that it did not find the receiving mailaddress and some kind of errorhandling for that?

The Gmail API doesnt present a solution to my eye on how to prevent this issue.

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending?hl=en

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/labels?hl=en